# How to get length of query result SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have simple query using SqlAlchemy ORM:

```
query = DBsession.query(AssetsItem).filter_by(
    AssetsItem.id > 10,
    AssetsItem.country = 'England'
)
```

How can i get length of my query result. I want to know how much AssetsItem i would get by this query

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
query = DBsession.query(AssetsItem).filter_by(
AssetsItem.id > 10,
AssetsItem.country = 'England'
)
your_count = query.count()
```

[Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count)

Comment: This answer was done long time ago, but for *future* reference, just make clear that the .count() after the query will actually perform a new query. It's well documented here:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count.